# SalesForce REST API INVALID_SESSION_ID error using v38.0

Tags: rest, oauth, salesforce

I am using SalesForce REST API For my PHP Application 
But, when I send request at "instance_url/services/data/v38.0" along with the access token , I get this error:

```
[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]
```

I have a developer salesforce account and have API enabled true for every profile.

This is my Headers:

```
$headers = array(
          "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Accept:application/json",
          "Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token
          );
```

Used in CURL.